# Display all files in MAMP htdocs through browser

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, netbeans, mamp

I recently purchased a new MacBook Pro (10.8 OS) and installed MAMP 3.0 (not MAMP-Pro) but I have been searching the web on how to display all files when viewing a folder within the `htdocs` directory such as: `htdocs/stackoverflow` VIA the browser (Chrome or Firefox).  This is a feature that I do not have a problem with in Windows using either WAMP or XAMPP when navigating to the `localhost/directory/contents`.  I do understand that `localhost` must be accessed through `locahost:8888` or whatever port it has been modified to.  I do not have an issue starting or stopping the MAMP server and everything is executable through NetBeans 8.0 when I set a `.php` file as the index:

[image]

So just to be clear, if I have a directory under htdocs (`htdocs/foobar/`) filled with several `.php` files I want to be able to view them in the sub-directory of htdocs instead of a blank browser (tested within Chrome and Firefox).  I would imagine this is a security setting I am missing in the configuration?  How would I enable, for local development, the ability to view all files, directories, and contents VIA the web browser?  If it helps or may be an issue I am using NetBeans 8.0 as my IDE for PHP.

### Windows:

```
localhost
-stackoverflow
--foo.php
--bar.php
--humpday.php
```

### Mac:

```
localhost:8888
-stackoverflow
--empty in browser (chrome or Firefox)
```

I have searched to see if this a `php.ini` feature,  [MAMP 3 documentation](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/MAMP-3-User-Guide.pdf) has nothing on this, and Netbeans shows nothing per the search.

Comment: You can use htaccess to allow directory listing https://support.tigertech.net/directory-index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after much research and the help from Kevbot and Matt Thompson I was able to figure out what to do and it is as followed:

You should enable all hidden files in Mac that are default hidden.  To do this open a terminal (`Finder > Applications > Utilities > Terminal`)  I originally referenced this [site](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) but it was wrong in regards to showing hidden files for OSX 10.8:

### WRONG:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

### RIGHT:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

After doing so I held down the <kbd>option</kbd> + clicking `Finder` at the same time to prompt Relaunch of `Finder`.

[image]

You will need to navigate to MAMP (in this case MAMP 3.0 non-pro) in the Applications folder to `MAMP > conf > apache > httpd.conf`.

Open file in a text editor and search for `Options Indexes`.  It was line 202 for me.

**Change:**

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOveride None
</Directory>
```

**TO:**

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOveride All
</Directory>
```

Create an `.htaccess` file in the desired directory and add:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
```

Launch/relaunch MAMP.  Do note that if you have an index anything (`.php`, `.html`. `.xhtml`, etc. etc.) will show this instead of the directory listing

Answer (score 3):

**Actual Answer:**

You need to modify the .htaccess file in your root directory.

I was able to get this to work with no issues. In your .htaccess, add the following:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
DirectoryIndex somethingRandom.html
```

Here is what each line does:

- Line 1 specifies to allow the indexing of files.
- Line 2 tells the browser to display more information regarding the files
- Line 3 tells the browser the default index file is not index.php or index.html. Just set the file to something that will never exist.

**Old Answer:**

There are several things you can do to configure MAMP.

You don't have to access MAMP with localhost:8888, you can access it with just localhost with the following changes. If you open the MAMP program, and select:

1. Preferences
2. Ports
3. Set to default Apache and MySQL ports

Then, you can access your server through localhost in the web browser. Also, if you want to switch development folders (using a subfolder of htdocs as it's own site) you can configure those as well. Select the following from the MAMP program window:

1. Preferences
2. Apache
3. Select (a folder inside of htdocs)

Now, when you access localhost in the browser, that folder will be your root folder until you change it back to htdocs.

And just to make sure, did you remember to "Start Servers?"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you are missing what my question is.  I already know how to access, start, and modify the folder and ports.  My question is in regards to viewing the directory through the browser how can I set all files and folders to visible like you would get when running in Windows.

Comment: @Gramps so when you type localhost into the browser when MAMP is running, you don't see any of your folders, or an index.php? Also, what version of MAMP are you using?

Comment: @Gramps I was able to get this configured for my MAMP server. I am able to view all files as a directory listing with detailed information regarding each file. See the modified answer for details.